# Add new field to table and Edit Form Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony and have inherited a project that was originally php custom and is now half and half with Symfony 3.

I have very little knowledge of Symfony but work a good amount in php.

I wanted to add a field to the products table named "majoritem"

I have added majoritem to the Products class, added it to the form builder, added it to the table through phpmyadmin.

I can see the new form item when the app builds the form.

If I change the field in the database manually it does not reflect in the form.

My assumption is I am not binding the field to a form field?

Any help would be much appreciated.

In the form builder I have the following now (shortened..):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $companyId = $builder->getData()->getCompanyId();
    $builder
        ->add('productCode')
        ->add('name')
        ->add('productType', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Primary' => 'Primary',
                'Secondary' => 'Secondary'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('majoritem', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'No' => '0',
                'Yes' => '1'
            ]
        ])
        ]);
}
```

The Update action for the form is as follows:

```
   public function updateAction(Request $request, $productId)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EcoModelBundle:Products')
        ->find($productId);

    if (!$product)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested product could not be found');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductsType::class, $product);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $product = $form->getData();

        try
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Product updated successfully');
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'There was an error while saving the product. '
                . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid())
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'The submitted data is invalid');
    }

    return $this->render('@EcoProducts/Product/update.html.twig', [
        'product' => $product,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Finally, the Products class is as follows:

```
    class Products
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="company_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $companyId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_code", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $productCode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="majoritem", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $majoritem;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyId
     *
     * @param integer $companyId
     *
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setCompanyId($companyId)
    {
        $this->companyId = $companyId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCompanyId()
    {
        return $this->companyId;
    }






    /**
     * Set productCode
     *
     * @param string $productCode
     *
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setProductCode($productCode)
    {
        $this->productCode = $productCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get productCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductCode()
    {
        return $this->productCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }


    /**
     * Set majoritem
     *
     * @param integer $majoritem
     *
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setMajoritem($majoritem)
    {
        $this->majoritem = $majoritem;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get majoritem
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMajoritem()
    {
        return $this->majoritem;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->details = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add detail
     *
     * @param \EcoModelBundle\Entity\ProjectDetails $detail
     *
     * @return Products
     */
    public function addDetail(\EcoModelBundle\Entity\ProjectDetails $detail)
    {
        $this->details[] = $detail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove detail
     *
     * @param \EcoModelBundle\Entity\ProjectDetails $detail
     */
    public function removeDetail(\EcoModelBundle\Entity\ProjectDetails $detail)
    {
        $this->details->removeElement($detail);
    }

    /**
     * Get details
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }
}
```

So, interestingly I made a couple of changes..
the following is within my products class

```
    /**
 * Set majoritem
 *
 * @param integer $majoritem
 *
 * @return Products
 */
public function setMajoritem($majoritem)
{
    $this->majoritem = $majoritem;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get majoritem
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getMajoritem()
{
    return $this->majoritem;
}
```

Those do not seem to be working, or at least maybe I should say the getMajoritem is not?

If I change the form field to a simple text field as opposed to a dropdown, the form shows up as blank when the underlying data of the field is a zero.

However if I enter a 1 and submit the form it updates the database field to a 1.

So I am wondering if my issue is actually that the form builder is not retrieving the field value and adding it to the form?

Comment: You said you can see the form being displayed in the app, what is the problem then ? You want to change the field name in database without changing the code and the form get displayed ?

Comment: Yes, the field is displaying in the form but the field value is not attached to the field nor does it update the field when the form is submitted.  That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Just before `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` can you add `dump($product, $form->getData())`. Do you see your value in both object?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the mapping is correct using doctrine with the following command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate.
```

If it is correct, you can update the database schema with the schema, which we have previously validated, with the following command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force.
```

This will ensure that the mapping is being done through Doctrine and if there is an error in the medium, the ORM Doctrine will take care of notifying you.

Also I suggest that you change the schema by using migrations, check if your project is doing it and maybe you should update the schema through migrations:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

That will create a file in `src/Migrations/Version[timestamp].php`

And to update the schema of the database you must do it in the following way:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --up [timestamp]
```

And if you want to reverse the schema update you do it with:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --down [timestamp].
```

The advantage between using `schema:update` and `migrations` is that with the latter you can reverse the schema update operation

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for my newbie questions.  Will running any of the above commands overwrite any data within my database?  I don't know when the commands above have last been run or even if they have...  We may have items that have been put into database tables and fields via phpmyadmin as opposed to ORM.  Will this mess them up at all?  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Exact! The data you previously have on the database will be lost. Make a copy of the database before running these commands

Answer (score 0):

Try integer values for your form instead of string values as the mapped field in the entity is of type integer:

```
->add('majoritem', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'No' => 0, // <--- instead of '0'
            'Yes' => 1 // <--- instead of '1'
        ]
    ])
```